# MySql select Not Work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table .

one meal table

```
id   type

1    lunch
2    lunch
3    dinner
```

two user_history table

```
ID Meal_id  User_id  create  

1   2         4       1404638939
```

Now I want to select all meal from table one but have condition

if table two meal_id match with Meal table id and that create date same as current date   then skip that row from table one

I use this code but not work correctly

```
SELECT m.* FROM `meal` AS m LEFT JOIN user_history
                 ON user_history.meal_id != m.id and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_history.create))!=CURRENT_DATE() where m.meal_type = 'Lunch'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.* FROM `meal` AS m 
LEFT JOIN user_history
ON user_history.Meal_id != m.id and date(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_history.create))=CURRENT_DATE() 
where m.type LIKE "%lunch%"
```

Comment: Using = may not help you as you are looking for a string "lunch" hence use = when you have an exact match use '%lunch%' when you are not sure.

Comment: Also make sure you use right column names [Case Sensitive].

Comment: And pity the poor index

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the question, I'd say:

```
SELECT m.* FROM `meal` AS m 
    WHERE m.meal_type = 'Lunch'
        AND m.id NOT IN (
            SELECT meal_id FROM user_history
                WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_history.create))=CURRENT_DATE()
        )
```